# Java Fastest way to write data using BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, io, bufferedinputstream

I am reading data over the network(Salesforce) in an InputStream. And then adding buffering to it by using BufferedInputStream to read larger chunks of bytes instead of one byte at a time to speed up IO and writing it to file using OutputStream.

I think the code can be further optimized probably I am missing something to improve performance. As there are 3 CSV files that I am reading from Network after writing in ZIP, each file contains 50,000 rows and 150 columns, the size of CSV is roughly 250 MB. For each file to write its taking 1 min can it be reduced to 20-30 seconds for each file? Considering CSVWriter can write millions of data of ResultSet in a few mins.

**SystemDetails:**

```
RAM - 32 GB
CPU - Intel i7 @2.60GHz (2 Cores, 4 logical processors)
Java 8 
Windows 10
Internet Speed around 50 Mbps.
```

Code:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
  BufferedInputStream buffInput = null;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  String filenameformat = "File_Name";
  ZipOutputStream outputStream = null;
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inputStream =  bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(String batches);
  outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(datapath)));
  buffInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream,1024);
  outputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filenameformat + ".csv") );
  int length;
  while ((length = buffInput.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{  
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);  
}
buffInput.close();
outputStream.closeEntry();
outputStream.finish();
outputStream.flush();
```

Comment: Compressing data takes a while, and you're compressing a lot.

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes I am doing it intentionally to save disk space, Still I tried to write files without compression performance is improved but hardly by few seconds so I don't think that's the culprit here. Is there anything else that can be done maybe something to tweak with buffer size? 

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

Comment: The default buffer that the Buffered streams use should be correct, for the most part.

Comment: Ok, in that case, are you saying 1 min of writing time for 1 file is expected? (Even without compression)

Comment: No. I don't know your system. You could be using a Raspberry Pi to write on paper tape for all I know. But you're reading, modifying, and writing 250 MB files. It's not going to be instantaneous.

Comment: I have updated the post with core system details. In case if that helps.